# Angular timer for multiple instance

Tags: angularjs, timer

I am referring t JSBIN link here (http://jsbin.com/qoletejusa/edit?html,js,output)

The timer works for one instance.

What if I want multiple timer running at different time? Lets assume there is 5 timer. I click start on one and after 10 seconds I click start on the second and after 7 seconds I click start on the third and so on...

But right now if I have 5 timer it all runs at once no matter which start button I click.

How should I fix this?

Comment: this code isn't designed to do what you want.  You would need to completely redesign a timer service that accepted multiple variables and/or didn't rely upon `$broadcast`.  Explaining how to go about this is too broad for this format.

Comment: @Claies Do you know or come across angular tips that satisfies the requirements? I am thinking of creating new objects for each instance... but not really sure how to do it...